# Any Debugger which can debug itcl code

Tags: tcl

I am wondering if there is any debugger available which can debug itcl code.
I used komodo and Ram debugger but it does not work  for debugging itcl . So please let me know if any debugger is there or any other way except using puts, which i can use to debug the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm. Komodo is the one I would have thought could have done it, given that the TclDevKit (which has probably the best Tcl debugger) is published by the same company.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply . I tried in every way using komodo , but it step over during debugging itcl code. We have a project which is completely based on itcl . Using komodo or TCL devkit i am not able to do debugging. Please let me know , if there is any script or any debugger which can help me.